# Performing functions in two `then` inside componentDidMount ()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Expected effect:
Response from the first request save in the variable `check = res.data`. The variable `check` wants to pass the second request to the condition`if (!check) {}`. However, `check` is always empty. I have an error:

> Error: "check" is read-only

```
  componentDidMount() {  
    this.getTodos();
  }

  getTodos = (userId) => {
    const check = {};
    axios({
      url: "/api/v1/todos",
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(response => {  
      check = response.data;
      if(response.data[0]) {   
        this.setState({
          todos: response.data
        });

        this.loadTodo(response.data[0].id);   
      } 
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(() => {     
       if(!check) {
         this.loadT();
       }
    });
  }

loadTodo =  (id) => {
    const asset_id=  this.state.asset_id;
    axios({
        url: `/api/v1//load-todo/${id}`,
        method: "GET"
    })
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            loadTodo: response.data
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: I take it the `.catch` in the middle is so if the first request fails, the second is done?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry. I made a wrong question. Response from the first request save in the variable `check = res.data`. The variable `check` wants to pass the second request to the condition` if (! Check) {} `. However, `check` is always empty. I have an error: Error: "check" is read-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the reference of `check` declared as [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

When you declare a variable as `const`, you "can" change the property of it, but not the variable itself.

```
getTodos = (userId) => {
  // . .. 
    const check = {};
    axios({ ... })
    .then(response => {  
      check = response.data;
      // ... rest removed for brevity
  }
```

So you might want to declare it using [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), which has the same "block level" scope as `const` does but can be re-assigned.

```
let check = {}
...
```